# Without any hook or ext how do I have Language-ext_*.properties file?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Hi might be this is a silly question, but as I am beginner learner of liferay so this is confusing me. In my project's liferay/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/content/ we have some Language-ext_*.properties file, but as I have searched in project there is no ext and even there is no hook corresponding to this properties file.

I also dont know how we can have our customized files inside ROOT directory.

Comment: what you want to achieve using properties file? do you have any portlet?

Comment: @LuckyBoy yaa I have many portlet. Actually I need to overrride Language_ru.properties file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My `WEB-INF/classes` directory contains only these files/directories (wildcarded for the legacy ones):

```
log4j.properties
logging.properties  
META-INF
portal-legacy-*.properties  
portal-developer.properties
```

So my guess is that someone manually put those files there. It's quite common to see that somebody did this. However, my recommendation is to not accept this mode of operation: It's tempting to fix something quickly with those files, without proper documentation. In case you'll have to restore the server any time in the future, you're never getting the same configuration/changes together again, so I'd purely demand to deploy *all* files within webapps/ROOT through plugins from everybody working with the system.

As you state in your comment, everything you want is to add russian translation, just do so [with a hook](https://www.liferay.com/de/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/overriding-a-language-properties-file): It's standard operation for this type of plugin and it's easy to maintain. Plus, it's best practice, hot deployable and quickly done

Comment: Hi thanks for your detail explanation. Ya I want to override  Language_ru.properties, but the file with the name Language-ext_ru.properties is already there in mentioned path. I tried to hook manytimes through various ways suggested in many sites including Liferay but due to high priority of Languange-ext_ru.properties I am not able to do so.

Comment: Try to figure out who put the file there and why. Then convert it to a hook (e.g. merge it into your hook) and remove it from the server. It doesn't belong there in the first place - unless it has been deployed by another plugin (in that case: Identify the plugin and fix that instead of adding a new one)